# Always send certain values with an ajax request/post

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm building a system that displays a list of user, and on selection of a user requests some form of password. These values are saved in a hidden field on the page, and need to be sent with every request as a form of authentication. (I'm aware of the MITM-vulnerability that lies herein, but it's a very low-key system, so security is not a large concern).

Now I need to send these values with each and every request, to auth the currently 'logged in' user. I'd like to automate this, via `ajaxSetup`, however i'm running into some issues.

My first try was:

```
init_user_auth: function(){
    $.ajaxSetup({
        data: {
            'user'    : site_user.selected_user_id(),
            'passcode': site_user.selected_user_pc(),
            'barcode' : site_user.selected_user_bc()
        }
    });
},
```

However, as I should have known, this reads the values once, at the time of the call to `ajaxSetup`, and never rereads them. What I need is a way to actually call the functions every time an ajax-call is made.

I'm currently trying to understand what is happening here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/jquery-dev/OBcEfgvTJ9I, however through the flamewar and very low-level stuff going on there, I'm not exactly sure I get what is going on.

Is this the way to proceed, or should I just face facts and manually add login-info to each ajax-call?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If i got you right, then see this sample code, it adds certain values to each ajax request,

```
(function ($) {
    var _ajax = $.ajax,
    A = $.ajax = function(options) {                    
        if (typeof options.data == 'object') {                      
            $.extend( options.data, A.data );
        } else if (typeof options.data == 'string' && options.data.length > 0) {
            for (var key in A.data) {
                options.data += '&' + encodeURIComponent(key) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(A.data[key]);
            }
        } else {
            options.data = A.data;
        }
        return _ajax(options);
    };
})(jQuery);
```

And you call it like:

```
$.ajax.data = { "user": 10, "pass" : 20 }; //params that always need to be passed
```

Then ajax call,

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost/blg/crl_chk.php",
    data : { "first" : 1},  //now those params will be added wit this
    success: function(resp) {
    console.log( resp );
    }
});
```

In case you call `$.ajax` with no data, those params will be passed.

Did you mean something like this

Comment: This looks like what I wasn't able to deduce from the google discussion I mentioned, I'll give it a try ASAP, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the functions you would like to have called are called only when the Ajax settings object is being merged with your stub. (presumably during the first ajax request)

What you can do is make your data object reference global variables instead of functions.

"But that won't call the function at each call to `$.ajax()` you say?

Just make the call to your functions at `.ajaxSend()` or `.ajaxStart()` and have them update the global vars!

http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSend/

http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/

Comment: Hmm, interesting idea, but @sudhir's method seems cleaner. If I crash and burn on that, I'll give this a try! Thanks!

Comment: I think I would have preferred this solution, but it fails the 10-second copy paste test. The other answer works out of the box.